# Make a view within a relative layout the same size as a scroll view

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to have a semi transparent view over my relative layout and it works fine until i rotate the screen or display an error message inside if a TextInputLayout. The problem occurs when the layout needs a scroll view in order to view all of the elements.
Below is the code I am using to have this background cover my relative layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundImage">

<View
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:alpha="0.79"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My question is how can i have the custom view to be the same size as the scroll view all the time.

Comment: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` should probably be `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` then in your parent layout (RelativeLayout).

Comment: unfortunately that didn't do the trick. When i rotate the screen the custom view disappears

Comment: Can you gather logs about what happens in your `onOrientationChange` ? Try gathering some logs and posting them too, they'll help.

Comment: When i rotate the screen i get 5 information messages declaring Too many attribute references, stopped at:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use linear layout instead of relative layout and and set layout weight 1  and it will work for every angle

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the RelativeLayout attributes to these

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

and it should do the work.